# How to split up authors (lists) into columns?

Tags: biblatex, lists

I would like to have the authors split up into columns of multicols.
The problem is I don’t get the `\value{listtotal}` to define the count of columns dynamically.

So, for one author there should be only one column, for two authors two columns and so on.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{3pt}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{example1,
author = {Author, A.}}

@book{example2,
author = {Author, A. and Buther, B.}}

@book{example3,
author = {Author, A. and Buther, B. and Cuthor, C.}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{
  %\hfil.    %this is working but not wanted
  \par\columnbreak}
\let\finalnamedelim\multinamedelim

\newcommand\name{}
\newcommand\getname[2][\name]{%
    \begin{multicols}{3} %\value{listtotal} ???
    \citename{#1}{#2}%
    \end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
% one multicol-environment
\def\name{example1}
\getname{author}

% two multicol-environment
\def\name{example2}
\getname{author}

% three multicol-environment
\def\name{example3}
\getname{author}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At the point where you need to use `\value{listtotal}` here the value is not defined. `listtotal` is only populated with the correct value in certain situations when you are "inside" `biblatex`'s list printing routines. The number of authors is not available at that point for you.

Comment: I thought that is the case, so probably no chance to get the number of items in that list?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments the counter `listtotal` is only populated with the value you need in the specific context of `biblatex` list printing. In particular it is not available outside of list printing in `biblatex`, much less outside of `biblatex` itself. You need to get hold of the value before you start your multicolumn. That could be done using a fake citation command.

I must say that I find the interface/argument structure of the macro `\getname` really confusing, but I assume that it is useful for the purpose you designed it for.

Note that `multicols` still provides two columns even if the argument is `1`. You have to treat that case separately.

`\multicolumnauthor` is the solution I would use, but it has the drawback of adding additional space between several `multicols` because of `\leavevmode`, so that might not be applicable to you.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{3pt}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{example1,
author = {Author, A.}}

@book{example2,
author = {Author, A. and Buther, B.}}

@book{example3,
author = {Author, A. and Buther, B. and Cuthor, C.}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\endgraf\columnbreak}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\getnumberofauthors}
  {}
  {\xdef\numofnames{\the\value{author}}}
  {}
  {}

\newcommand\name{}
\newsavebox{\discardbox}
\newcommand\getname[2][\name]{%
  \def\numofnames{1}%
  \sbox{\discardbox}{\getnumberofauthors{#1}}%
  \begin{multicols}{\numofnames}
  \citename{#1}{#2}%
  \end{multicols}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\multicolumnauthor}
  {}
  {\ifnumgreater{\value{author}}{1}
     {\begin{multicols}{\value{author}}
      \printnames{author}%
      \end{multicols}}
     {\printnames{author}}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
% one multicol-environment
\def\name{example1}
\getname{author}

% two multicol-environment
\def\name{example2}
\getname{author}

% three multicol-environment
\def\name{example3}
\getname{author}

\multicolumnauthor{example1}
\multicolumnauthor{example2}
\multicolumnauthor{example3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew with your biblatex magic power you would find a solution. Indeed `getname` looks weird separated by the rest of code I use. However `\DeclareCiteCommand{\multicolumnauthor}` is nice code, I will go with the `savebox` since the case for one author and two columns is no problem in my document. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok, ok, you convinced me and I changed my internal code to `\DeclareCiteCommand{\multicolumnauthor}` etc and I found a workaround for `\leavemode`, because now I can check whether the field is empty or not which is important to my code.